# explode_outer splits the column into 2 rows if one of the json parameter has value with "\n" in it

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, explode, outer-join

I am trying to execute a spark notebook in which I am trying to process json file which has the a json array in one of columns named "data" :

```
[{"payload":"here to check 1.\n checking again 1", "key1": " value1"},
 {"payload":"here to check 2.\n checking again 2", "key1": " value2"}]
```

I use `explode_outer()` to split the column "data" into different rows where each json in the array makes 1 row. So I expect 2 rows as results.
The problem is instead of 2 rows, I get 4 rows. It seems to split on the `"\n"` in the "payload" parameter of the json. Could anybody guide me on how to fix this? 
 eg: json:

```
{"alldata" : [{"payload":"here to check 1.\n checking again 1", "key1": " value1"},
{"payload":"here to check 2.\n checking again 2", "key1": " value2"}], "alldata1": "any"}
```

code:

```
    var load =  spark.read.schema(schema).json(path);
      var queryValTemp = load.select(
            col("alldata1"),
       explode_outer(col("alldata")).as("explode_data")
            );
        queryValTemp.show();
```

Comment: @ollik1: I am not sure if it's duplicate because I am able to read the data into correct column. the \n is within a value of one of json parameters and the issue occurs only when I call the explode method

Comment: do you have a reproducible example of the issue?

Comment: @ollik1: I have edited the question with the code sample

Comment: Ok, removed the duplicate flag. For me the sample works as expected, getting two rows as output.

Comment: how about if the \n is at the end of the line. `{"alldata" : [{"payload":"here to check 1.\n checking again 1\n", "key1": " value1"},
{"payload":"here to check 2.\n checking again 2\n", "key1": " value2"}], "alldata1": "any"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I discovered, if there are \n in a column with json; calling explode_outer() will split one column into 2 rows instead of 1. The only way to solve this is before calling explode_outer():

- call to_json() on the column
- replaceAll() for removing \n.
- call from_json() on the result of replaceAll.